# MD5 Hashing Given a Key in C#

Tags: c#, md5, hash

I've been looking for a way to hash a given string in C# that uses a predetermined key.

On my adventures through the internet trying to find an example i have seen lots of MD5CryptoServiceProvider examples which seem to use a default key for the machine, but none of them that apply a specific key.   I need to have a specific key to encode data as to synchronize it to someone else's server. I hand them a hashed string and an ID number and they use that analyze the data and return a similar set to me.  So is there anyway to get md5 to hash via a specific key that would be consistent to both.

I would prefer this to be done in C#, but if its not possible with the libraries can you do so with some web languages like php or asp?

Edit: Misunderstood the scenario I was thrown into and after a little sitting and thinking about why they would have me use a key it appears they want a key appended to the end of the string and hashed.  That way the server can appended the key it has along with the data passed to ensure its a valid accessing computer.   Anyways... thanks all ^_^

Edit2: As my comment below says, it was the term 'salting' I was oblivious to.  Oh the joys of getting thrown into something new with no directions.

Comment: There is no key for MD5... as Tom Ritter pointed out, it's **not** an encryption algorithm

Comment: As everyone's pointed out MD5 is hashing, not encryption, but it's not clear from your post if you actually *do* want hashing and misspoke or really want encryption. Clarify please.

Comment: Your edit didn't really clarify your question. MD5 uses no "predetermined key" that you are asking about. However, if all you need to do is compare hashes then simply take the hash of your two inputs and compare the results bit-for-bit. Note that MD5 will usually (barring the very unlikely case of hash collision) give completely different results even if the inputs vary by the smallest amount.

Comment: I think he means he wants to salt the string to hash.  That way the server can validate the input using the same salt.

Comment: Yea I looked up salting thats what I need. Stupid work tossing me into something I'm completely oblivious to. At least i learned something new huh.

Comment: FYI, the addition of an extra pre-determined string to the end of another string before hashing it is called 'salting'. The predetermined string is called the 'salt'. For example, if I wanted to hash 'incrediman' using the salting technique, I would append a predetermined salt such as '1234', and then hash the entire thing: md5("incrediman1234").

Then let's say you came along and had to enter my username for authentication purposes. You would enter 'incrediman', and I would append '1234' before hashing and authenticating just like I did when originally hashing the string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MD5 is not encryption - it's a hash.  It doesn't allow a string to be decrypted.

You're looking for a symmetric encryption algorithm.  It uses the same key to encrypt and decrypt.  Trying to use encryption functions [without understanding them is dangerous](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001267.html).  Even if you think you understand them, you can make a mistake.

If you're transferring data to another person's server, you may be better off using something like [gpg](http://gnupg.org/) to encrypt the file using a symmetric key you both agree on over the phone, *or* perhaps some public-key crypto.  This way, you don't write any crypto code, and it's safer (not completely secure, mind you, but safer).

---

**Edit:** I'm still trying to decipher your requirements.

MD5 is an unkeyed hash function - there is not key in use at all.  So let's say the server sends you a giant string, or a file, and a hash of it.  You would then MD5 the string or file, and compare the hash you computed with the hash they sent.  If they match - the data was **not corrupted in transit**.  That *doesn't* mean no one tampered with what they sent you in transit, because MD5 has no "secret sauce" to it.  I can md5 anything I want and send it to you.

A HMAC is a *keyed hash function*.  It has a secret ingredient that only you and the group you're communicating with should know - the secret key.  If they send you a long string or file, and a HMAC, you can compute the HMAC yourself, compare your HMAC and theirs, and if they match, **the data was not corrupted in transit, nor was the data tampered with**.

Answer (score 2):

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a hash function and, strictly speaking, is not used to "encrypt" a string. It produces a 128-bit "Message Digest" (hence the MD in the name) that is used as a kind of fingerprint for the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Tom's right: MD5 is just a one-way hash, you can't decrypt it. Try these links:

- [Symmetric Key Encryption in C#](http://www.obviex.com/samples/Code.aspx?Source=EncryptionCS&Title=Symmetric%20Key%20Encryption&Lang=C%23)
- [Public-Key RSA Encryption in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/RSACryptoPad.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AES from C# to do the type of encryption you are looking for.  Here's [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164055.aspx) on how.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the classes inherited from `SymmetricAlgorithm`, for instance :

- AesCryptoServiceProvider
- DESCryptoServiceProvider
- RC2CryptoServiceProvider
- TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider

Answer (score 0):

So, why does the following test fail if both input strings are identical?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MD5HashTest()
    {
        var hash1 = (new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()).ComputeHash(new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("now is the time for all good men."));
        var hash2 = (new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()).ComputeHash(new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("now is the time for all good men."));

        Assert.AreEqual(hash1, hash2);
    }
```

Comment: This is because Assert.AreEqual is checking reference equality: hash1 and hash2 are different objects, therefore your test fails. If you look at the contents of hash1 and hash2, however, you'll see that they contain the exact same set of bytes.