# MD5 Encryption with Key

Tags: python, python-2.7, debian, md5, md5sum

I am trying to Hash a txt file using MD5 Algorithm , the problem is I want to hash the text file using a special key for a security reason.
where the idea is to have two machines exchanging messages and applying security check through the MD5 hash of the messages using a secret key.
and no one should know this specific key.

My machine is Linux based (Debian OS).
and I am using python as a programing language.

I already digged through the internet and I can find an MD5 library in python but it doest have the option of changing the key used

#

```
import md5

import string

hash = md5.new()

hash.update("this is the text to be hashed")

value = hash.digest()

print hash.hexdigest()
```

#

I also tried to use Debian standard library MD5sum but still I cannot figure how to change the key used to creat the hash.

Appreciate if any one has any ideas, I cannot use any online tool because I want to include this MD5 hash in my python program or at least using standard Debian Library.

I cannot use any C# or php or any other programing tool except python and standard linux libraries.

Thanks alot

Comment: possible duplicate of [MD5 Hashing Given a Key in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088916/md5-hashing-given-a-key-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "key" in this context? A [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `hmac` module in python to key-hash a message. More info [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hmac.html).

Here's a sample program:

```
import hmac
import md5

hash_key = 'secret hashing key'
hash = hmac.new(hash_key, 'this is the text to be hashed', md5)
value = hash.digest()
print hash.hexdigest()
```

Comment: actually for security purposes you shouldn't reuse the salt, but instead generate a random new one for every hash operation and store it along with the hash.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use the salt technique , as the other server uses a fixed MD5 with a secret key.

Answer (score 1):

thanks alot for ur feedback and answers , I found a way to use a secret key authentication called HMAC (Hashed Message Authentication Code)
and it

## echo -n 'value' | openssl dgst -md5 -hmac 'key'

(stdin)= 01433efd5f16327ea4b31144572c67f6

for more information u can refer to the openssl library

openssl dgst [-md5|-md4|-md2|-sha1|-sha|-mdc2|-ripemd160|-dss1] [-c] [-d] [-hex] [-binary] [-out filename] [-sign filename] [-keyform arg] [-passin arg] [-verify filename] [-prverify filename] [-signature filename] [-hmac key] [file...]
[md5|md4|md2|sha1|sha|mdc2|ripemd160] [-c] [-d] [file...]

where the key authentication is explained as follow:

-hmac key:create a hashed MAC using "key".

-mac alg:create MAC (keyed Message Authentication Code).

The most popular MAC algorithm is HMAC (hash-based MAC ), but there are other MAC algorithms which are not based on hash, for instance gost-mac algorithm, supported by ccgost engine. MAC keys and other options should be set via -macopt parameter.

for reference , I have used the below blog , and the MD5 man pages

http://nwsmith.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-openssl-to-generate-hmac-using.html

http://linux.die.net/man/1/md5